# Is there a way to use exec.Command to run a new process and honor the setgid bit on the target executable?

Tags: linux, go, system-calls

Edit: It seems the gid takes effect but the tool (1Password CLI2) I try to execute does not work with the way `exec.Command` is implemented.

---

I'm trying to call an executable from go with [exec.Command](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Command) which needs certain permissions granted by its owning group. The [setgid](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setgid) bit is set on that executable.

Calling it from exec.Command does not honor the setgid bit and providing credentials which set additional groups does not work without root privileges.

Using [syscall.Exec](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Exec) ---does actually set the correct group since it uses [execvg](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), but I think there is not an easy method to catch the output.

Is there a way to use exec.Command and set the correct group without root privileges that I'm missing?

I'm using Go 1.18.3 on Fedora 36.

Minimal example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("op", "account", "get")

    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()

    fmt.Printf("%s\n%s", out, err)
}
```

Which results in an error due to the required gid not being set:

```
[ERROR] 2022/07/12 17:33:03 connecting to desktop app: read: connection reset, make sure the CLI is correctly installed and CLI Biometric Unlock is enabled in the 1Password app
```

Doing the same in Python does work:

```py
from subprocess import check_output

o = check_output(["op", "account", "get"])

print(o)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I try running a setgid binary with `exec.Command`, the setgid bit does indeed take effect.

Comment: I'm trying to call the 1Password CLI2 and use biometric unlock. This does require the process to have the gid of the [onepassword-cli group set](https://developer.1password.com/docs/cli/biometric-security#how-does-1password-cli-communicate-with-the-1password-app). Calling the CLI from Go using `exec.Command` does not work, the CLI cannot authenticate. Interestingly doing the same from Python using [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) does work, so I'm assuming the Go implementation does something differently.

Comment: It would help if you posted your code ([mcve]) is it may be something related to the exact way in which you run the Command.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I've added a small example.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica You're right. I tested with a small program that simply prints the real and effective gid and it seems to be set correctly. I guess 1Password does not just check the gid or does it in a way that does not work when the CLI is called from Go. I'm pretty much interested in what the difference is between the Python and the Go implementation. Guess I'll dig around a little more.

Comment: [1Password developer here] This was in fact a problem with a security check in the 1Password app that was a bit too strict. The latest beta release of 1Password for Linux ([8.10.8-24](https://releases.1password.com/linux/beta/#1password-for-linux-8.10.8-24)) contains a fix for this. The next stable release (8.10.8) will also contain this fix.